# Turn all workspaces into windows or split screen to show several workspaces at once

Tags: linux, workspace

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm a long time Windows user, I was used to have a lot of windows open at the same time, I was told I could use workspaces in linux to replace the need for multiple windows.
I was wandering if it was possible to have the screen seen when I press `Super + s` in a single workspace and all the windows in that workspace laid out as they were (for example, if I had 4 workspaces, each of them had a maximized window, when I press a combination of keys, all windows will be seen on the current workspace (top left workspace will occupy top left quarter of current workspace, and so on for each workspace's location).
Is there a way to toggle this view and workspace view? I mean, if I press `Super + I`, all the workspaces will turn into windows in my current workspace, and if I press `Super + I` again, it will return to what it was before.

Another way of putting this is making the `Super + s` screen interactable, so I can actually use the windows and not just switch workspaces.

How can this be done?

Thanks